# What's the most efficient way to create a live dashboard for Big Data using .Net in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, bigdata, azure-stream-analytics

Hypothetical simplified scenario:

I have an Asp.Net Core 3 API that takes in Pizza orders from Javascript.
A pizza is ordered, I Deserialize the object in the C# API.
I have now an object "Pizza":

```
{
   "name": "Margherita",
   "date": "20201502",
   "amount": "10"
   "ingredients": ["tomato", "mozzarella"]
}
```

I receive 100 millions pizza orders per day, I need a live Dashboard showing the orders, with a menu for searching historical data like "Yesterday", "This Month", "Last Year" etc..

I also need a list of the most ordered pizzas in a given timeframe, or top ingredients used.

**What is the most modern, efficient way using Microsoft Azure and C# to achieve such result?**

There are too many Queues, Data Factories, Lakes, Storage, Streams etc Analytics services to choose from.

I can think of 2 ways:

1)

- Send each pizza order to a queue like Service Fabric Queues, AzureStorage Queue or Event Hubs
- Dequeue the objects keeping them in memory temporarily
- After 10k or more elements are in memory, aggregate them in such way to satisfy future queries and save them to CosmosDB instead of saving each single order
- This is CPU inefficient and limited in future queries but save costs on storage since no single object is stored but just aggregated data

2)

- Send each pizza to a queue like Event Hubs or Stream Analytics
- Save each single object to a storage for "Big Data"
- Use Apache Spark on Azure or similar to query the data
- Create a worker role that every minute query the Dataset and create single aggregated records using for example the "date" as PartitionKey to show in the dashboard
- Unsure if delete the data to save on storage costs make sense

I think the #2 is the way to go but I'm undecided on what is the best "stack" for the task that is easy and cost efficient.

Comment: can you describe what metrics and queries you need on your dashboard? For example Stream Analytics isn’t great for running a query that says “show me all orders from Fred last month” but it is great for returning a constant stream of updated “count of orders in a sliding 5 minute window”. Basically the query is fixed and the data is streaming (sort of opposite of typical database queries where the data is fairly static and the queries can change)

Comment: The metrics/queries are like "Show me how many pizzas were ordered yesterday by user X" or "Show me the most used ingredients last month for all orders from XX city".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at implementing some technologies that follow the Lambda architecture. Basically that is separate hot path and cold path technologies. Here is a good [introduction](https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2016/08/what-is-the-lambda-architecture/) though I wouldn’t focus only on the technologies James mentions.

If you have some standing queries like “number of pizzas ordered in rolling 5 minute window” then Azure Stream Analytics can output a constant stream of these aggregations.

Then the pizza order events can be also archived in Blob storage for ingestion into some batch technology. For example, do a daily or hourly load to Azure SQL Data Warehouse (rebranded Azure Synapse Analytics recently). Then your app can run queries like “most popular pizza toppings last month” in an ad-hoc fashion. The combination of these hot path and cold path technologies should work better than trying to get one tool to do everything.

Another option is Spark. I would recommend looking at Spark streaming in Azure Databricks. You should be able to do streaming aggregations and also load Delta tables for batch queries for older time periods. This [article](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/07/19/simplify-streaming-stock-data-analysis-using-databricks-delta.html) might give you an example.